# Adding stateless properties to an entity framework 5 code first POCO model

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model which contains a JSON string, and would like to keep the parsed JSON.NET object along for the ride to prevent unnecessary re-parsings.

For example

```
public class JsonData {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Json { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to keep a JObject in there, and if possible on Json string's set re-parse it.  I wouldn't want to store it in the database.  As I write this, though, it just *feels wrong*...

What's a good way to carry an object which is the same 'data' (view?), just serialized on top of a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can add the `[NotMapped]` annotation to properties on your POCO that you want to use only in code and not store in the database;

```cs
public class MyPoco {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ThisObjectCachedAsJson { get; set; }

}
```

A more complete example for your Json cache needs, deviating from POCO land though;

```
public class MyPoco {

    private Guid _id;
    private string _myName;
    private string _jsonCache;

    public Guid Id { 
        get { return _id; } 
        set { _jsonCache = null; _id = value; }
    }

    public string MyName { 
        get { return _myName; } 
        set { _jsonCache = null; _myName = value; }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ThisObjectCachedAsJson { 
        get { 
            if(_jsonCache == null) 
                _jsonCache = <generate json>; 
            return _jsonCache; 
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to create a base class with the getter and just call a method there to set _jsonCache to null. That'll keep your classes a bit cleaner.

Comment: That would work really well if there was a way to update it on set of "MyName".  It would still work if not :)

Comment: @ccook Since afaik EF always calls your setters/getters to store/load your entities, you could set a "dirty" flag in all your normal property setters that tells the Json getter to re-serialize the object next time it's being read. You probably don't want to update the Json cache on every set operation since there can be quite a few when loading from the database :)

Comment: Perhaps the get; set; on "ThisObjectCacheAsJson" could be implemented to use a local member to serialize on demand and the set on "MyName" to clear the member?  It just feels so tainted at that point.

Comment: I think that would work :)  Silly question though - how can I implement set without changing EF's behavior?

Comment: Love it!!  Not sure if its still a POCO model? - but its a  nice solution for sure :) ty!

Comment: A bit new to EF, but no [NotMapped] attributes are required for private members?

Comment: [NotMapped] is required for both private and public properties, but not fields since EF (afaik) does not even support mapping for fields at all.

Comment: With that in mind I have the string property private, with the set constructing the JObject.  On the public [NotMapped] set I set the string property to JObject.toString().  This way JObject is the only property to the data which is now stored as a string in EF. It also *should* prevent bad Json from appearing... (Looking at you DBA!) Thanks again!